# HTMLBars how to get started?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there any guide how to start with [HTMLBars](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars)? I am following "building HTMLBars" section but finally I am stuck. I have run building tool and now I have files in my `dist` directory like this:

```
.
├── htmlbars-compiler.amd.js
├── htmlbars-runtime.amd.js
├── morph.amd.js
├── test
│   ├── htmlbars-compiler-tests.amd.js
│   ├── htmlbars-runtime-tests.amd.js
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── loader.js
│   ├── morph-tests.amd.js
│   ├── packages-config.js
│   ├── qunit.css
│   └── qunit.js
└── vendor
    ├── handlebars.amd.js
    └── simple-html-tokenizer.amd.js
```

Which should I add to my ember project and is that all or have I to do something more? Is this library ready or it is still unusable for ember?

Comment: I am here in 2016. Any one any help ?

Comment: Basically you need to switch to Ember 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not even close to ready yet, I'd love to give more info, but there really isn't any.  Last I heard they wanted it as a beta in 1.9, but we'll see.

Comment: Is there any way to speed up rendering other than precompiling views at the moment?

Comment: @estshy sure, grouping for example. There are a lot of examples in the [ember discussion forum](discuss.emberjs.com). I use lazy rendering at the moment to render my ItemList with up to 25000 items. Works great since appending the required additional 50 items is always fast!